# How to install nginx subs_filter as an package on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nginx

nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed the standard nginx package for Ubuntu, libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter is [also an official Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/httpd/libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter). Install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter
```